# How to checkbox, radio do checked? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, checkbox

I have this script

```
$('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','true');
    }
});
```

He add checked="checked" but radio or checkbox **is still** **un**checked and Request:All in Laravel dont see this. How to **edit this** to do this checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.prop()`.

```
// Check all checkboxes found
jQuery('[type="checkbox"]').prop( "checked", true );

// Uncheck all checkboxes found
jQuery('[type="checkbox"]').prop( "checked", false );
```

For more details read the [jQuery docs on .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)